# How can I detect or handle a Null Query result in MVC?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

The code below works for cases where there are already records in the Credit card table for the user who is logged in; however, when a user doesn't have an entry in the credit card table, the query finds zero records as expected.  The problem is, the statement  maxccid = query.Maxccid(); returns a Null and an InvalidOpeation exception is thrown. I can't make the ccid field in the database nullable as it is part of a primary key.  I need a way to detect if this query will return a null before I run it, or a way to trap it (preferably without a try catch, as this condition will happen for every new customer (Best practices for Try/Catch state this is not a proper use of Try/Catch).  Just a note to add that I'm using Entity Framework.

UPDATE 4/9/14:  I modified the query to fix the problem I reported in comments to Usesr FailedProgramming and Mike.  I still have the null problem though.

```
// Create CreditCard - Write to DB
    public ActionResult Create(CreditCard model)
    {
        EntitiesContext context = new EntitiesContext();
        int uid = (int)WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);  // Currently logged-in user
        short? maxccid = 0; //this will be the max ccid for this user

        var query = from c in context.CreditCards
                    where c != null && c.UserId == uid select c.CCID;
        maxccid = query.Max();
```

Comment: how about if(query.Any()) maxccid = query.Max();

Answer (score 1):

```
if(query.Any())
     maxccid = query.Max();
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  This didn't work for me.  It's strange, but if there are three or more records in the creditCard table, it performs as I expect (query.Any()) is true, else if there are one or two records, it equates to false which is not what I want.  I thought query.Any() was supposed to return true if the query returns one or more records?

Comment: I am still working on it, but I think this is working Michael.  I previously thought it wasn't, but I discovered an error in my query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `using` for the databse objects.
Secondly, use null-coalescing operator. for handling the null 
 Check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

```
public ActionResult Create(CreditCard model)
{

    using(EntitiesContext context = new EntitiesContext()) // using keyword will dispose the object properly.
    {
        int uid = (int)WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);  // Currently logged-in user
        short? maxccid = 0; //this will be the max ccid for this user

        var query = from c in context.CreditCards 
                where c.UserId == uid && c.CCID == (context.CreditCards.Max(c1 => c1.CCID) ) select c.CCID ;
        maxccid = query.Max() ?? 0; //use null-coalescing operator.
    }


}
```

You can optimize this code more as per your needs.
Hope, It may help you at some point. Have a nice day.

Comment: Pratik, thanks for taking a crack at this.  When I put in the using(EntitiesConext.... statement, it cause the context.CreditCards statment to not like context (underlined in red everywhere referenced).

Comment: The thing is you can use that context object in that particular using block only. you can't use it outside the scope. Do one thing dont use that using, if you can't get it. Just use the null colaescing operator, it will help you

Comment: Pratik, You can't use the Null Coalescing operator on objects of type short or int.  The code is working as it is, but what I've discovered is that the query is not producing consistent results.  When there are only 1 or two records in the CreditCards table, query.Max() returns a false value.  When there are three or more query.Max() returns a true value.  This is very frustrating.  I wonder if it has something to do with EntityFramwork in that I'm querying the context, and not the database directly?